# Where's my \sdk\extras\android\m2repository\ folder in Eclipse's Android SDK folder structure?

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-recyclerview

I have Android Support Library 21.0.1 and can update to 21.0.2 (though for fear of breaking things I'm not going to just yet - as the past has shown it's an enormous pain to "down"date, once you've updated something in Eclipse).

**I don't have this m2repository folder that everyone keeps referring to**, which I need to manually add the support-v7 compatability library in order to use a RecyclerView in my project.

**I'm using a target of Android 5.0 (API 21) Rev 1, SDK Tools 23.0.5, Platform-tools 21, Build-tools 20**. All the latest according to Eclipse and no folder is present.. How do I use a RecyclerView without having this specific v7 library available? I'm already using app-compat libraries v4 and v7 but not from this folder location..

Side question: Do libraries inherit other libraries? ie if I add "MyLibrary" which uses Facebook-SDK which uses app-compat-v4 is that the same as me simply using app-compat-v4 directly from my own Package?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I don't have this m2repository folder that everyone keeps referring to

That would be installed via the "Android Repository" in the SDK Manager.

> All the latest according to Eclipse and no folder is present

Unless you're using Maven with Eclipse, `m2repository` is not something you will use with Eclipse.

> How do I use a RecyclerView without having this specific v7 library available?

By using the library project, just as you did `appcompat-v7`. You will find a `recyclerview/` directory as a peer of `appcompat`, in the `extras/android/support/v7/` directory within your Android SDK installation.

> ie if I add "MyLibrary" which uses Facebook-SDK which uses app-compat-v4 is that the same as me simply using app-compat-v4 directly from my own Package?

For Eclipse users, `android-support-v4.jar` is a JAR. If Facebook's SDK is a library project, and it has `android-support-v4.jar` in `libs/`, and your app depends upon Facebook's library project, you will get `android-support-v4.jar` added to your project as well. Basically, everything in the library project is added to your app's project.

Comment: Thank you! I notice I didn't have the "Android Repository" add-on installed. 
Edit: Ohhh, I also just investigated the folder structure you mentioned and saw the appcompat folder there. Pwoah, it confuses me maintaining all of these libraries and their locations, they get updated then ones out of date so you create another project and add the new library then there's a conflict, then another library rely's on another version. Hectic. Thanks for your reply!